# Reshaping a data frame with a list column produced by tidygraph

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, tidygraph

I am working with the `tidygraph` package and try to find a "tidy" solution 
for the example below. The problem is not really tied to `tidygraph` and more about data wrangling but I think it is interesting for people working with this package.

In the following code chunk I just generate some sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(randomNames)
library(reshape2)

graph <- play_smallworld(1, 100, 3, 0.05) 

labeled_graph <- graph %>% 
                    activate(nodes) %>%
                    mutate(group = sample(letters[1:3], size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                           name = randomNames(100)
                           )

sub_graphs_df <- labeled_graph %>% 
                    morph(to_split, group) %>%
                    crystallise()
```

The resulting `data.frame` looks as follows:

```
sub_graphs_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      name           graph
     <chr>          <list>
1 group: a <S3: tbl_graph>
2 group: b <S3: tbl_graph>
3 group: c <S3: tbl_graph>
```

Now to my actual problem. I want do apply a function to each element in the column `graph`. The result is simply a named vector.

```
sub_graphs_df$graph %>% map(degree)
```

The first thing I do not like is the subsetting by `$`. Is there a better way?

Next, I want to reshape this result into only one data.frame with 3 columns. One column for `name` (the name attribute of the vectors), one for `group` (the name attribute of the list) and one for the `number` (the elements of the vectors).

I tried `melt` from the `reshape2` package.

```
sub_graphs_df$graph %>% map(degree) %>% melt
```

It works decently but the names are lost and as I read it, one should use 
`tidyr` instead. However, I could not get `gather` to work because only  `data.frames` are accepted.

Another option would be `unlist`:

```
sub_graphs_df$graph %>% map(degree) %>% unlist
```

Here the group and the name are in the names attribute and I would have to recover them with regular expressions.

I am pretty sure there is an easy way I just could not think of.

Comment: Another option is `sub_graphs_df %>% mutate(newout = map(graph, ~degree(.x)  %>% stack)) %>% .$newout %>% setNames(., sub_graphs_df$name) %>% bind_rows(., .id = 'name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `list` column with `mutate` while applying the function with `map`, extract the `names` and integer and `unnest` to create the 'long' format dataset

```
sub_graphs_df %>%
   mutate(newout = map(graph, degree)) %>%
   transmute(name, group = map(newout, ~.x %>% names), number = map(newout, as.integer)) %>%
    unnest
# A tibble: 100 x 3
#   name     group              number
#   <chr>    <chr>               <int>
# 1 group: a Seng, Trevor            0
# 2 group: a Buccieri, Joshua        1
# 3 group: a Street, Aimee           2
# 4 group: a Gonzalez, Corey         2
# 5 group: a Barber, Monique         1
# 6 group: a Doan, Christina         1
# 7 group: a Ninomiya, Janna         1
# 8 group: a Bazemore, Chao          1
# 9 group: a Perfecto, Jennifer      1
#10 group: a Lopez Jr, Vinette       0
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: From which package comes the abbreviation `~.x`?

Comment: @Alex The `map` is from `purrr` and also the related anonymous call